# php artisan migrate command migrate error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

While i run php artisan migrate. It will show the following error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'translations' already exists (SQL: create table `translations` (`
  id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `table_name` varchar(191) not null, `column_name` varchar(191) not null, `f
  oreign_key` int unsigned not null, `locale` varchar(191) not null, `value` text not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_a
  t` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'translations' already exists



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'translations' already exists
```

Before that i have run php artisan make:auth command and after that i have install voyager laravel admin panel and after that i run migrate command.

I can't figure out what's the issues with tables.

Comment: It looks like you're running a `Schema:: create` more than once in your migrations. Use `Schema::table` if you're changing an existing table.

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

try this ( If not work you need to clear the database with bare hands just drop tables and try php artisan migrate again good luck